# Breaking Up Meteor Schema in autoform

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I have a SimpleSchema that looks like this:

```
ArticleSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Title',
        max: 200
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Description',
        max: 1000,
    },
    video: {
        type: VideoSchema
    },
    date: {
        type: DateSchema
    },
    course: {
        type: CourseSchema
    },
    cat: {
        type: CatSchema
    },
    author: {
        type: AuthorSchema
    }
});

Articles.attachSchema( ArticleSchema );
```

Almost every type refers to another schema -- for instance, the date schema looks like this:

```
DateSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Date Created',
        optional: true
    },
    dateUpdated: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Date Updated',
        optional: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Created At',
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: 'hidden'
        }
    }
});
```

On the page that hosts the form I would like to break these sub-schemas up into different sections on the page for stylistic and ease of use reasons.  However, I only want to have one Submit button that will insert all the form data into the MongoDB.

I am using the collection2 and autoform packages.  I'm just not sure how exactly to use autoform to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Thanks and be well,

Moshe